# How to remove circular screws for 5” drive bay? Are they rivets?

Tags: computer-building

I have a system I built and I’m trying to remove the 5” drive bay I don’t use so I can install a 360mm radiator. However, the screws are circular…

[image]

[image]

Are these even safe to remove? Are they rivets instead of screws? Can I just take them out with some needle nose pliers? If I do will I be able to reassemble it?

Comment: They look like some slightly odd rivets, to me...

Comment: oh yes, that was an autocorrect typo and I don't have the reputation to post images, thank you

Comment: You'd be better off putting the radiator in another area of the case which has much better airflow, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are "[pop-rivets](http://www.stanleyengineeredfastening.com/brands/pop)".

From my experience, your best bet is to drill them out with a drill, using a bit that's slightly larger than the indent you see on the rivet.

Perhaps check out these how-tos:

- [How to Remove Rivets With a Drill Bit](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/remove-rivets-drill-bit-83651.html)
- [How to Remove a Pop Rivet Without a Drill](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/remove-pop-rivet-drill-85507.html)

Comment: Thank you! Would I be able to put them back in afterwards?

Comment: Nope, but you could use a nut and bolt, or just go get a pop rivet gun and some pop rivets and re-rivet it - they're pretty cheap. :)